# How to execute procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
pkg_name.Procedure_name (in_request_id IN table_name.in_request%type,
out_sts OUT VARCHAR2)

BEGIN 

pkg_name.Procedure_name (in_request_id => 31247499,
out_sts => 'OK');

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If procedure contains an `OUT` parameter, then *caller* has to have a variable to put that value into.

```
declare
  l_out varchar2(20);                                   --> this is the variable
begin
  pkg_name.procedure_name(in_request_id => 31247499,
                          out_sts       => l_out        --> use it here
                         );

  dbms_output.put_line('Procedure returned ' || l_out);
end;
/
```

---

Your code says

```
out_sts => 'OK'
```

That's what `procedure_name` should do, most probably somewhere at the end of the procedure so that it (the procedure) would indicate that everything went well.